# In vitro, in vivo, in situ, in simulacris mathematicis? Any good alternatives to the latter?

Tags: science, word-request

There is  a series of Latin and pseudo-Latin phrases used in a scientific context (mostly in the life sciences) describing how and where a study was carried out (sorted by [frequency](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+vivo%2Cin+vitro%2Cin+situ%2C((in+natura)*100)%2C(in+silico+%2B+in+silicio)*100%2C((in+simulacra+%2B+in+simulacris)*1000)%2C((in+papyro)*1000)&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20vivo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20vitro%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20situ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28in%20natura%29%20%2A%20100%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28in%20silico%20%2B%20in%20silicio%29%20%2A%20100%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28in%20simulacra%20%2B%20in%20simulacris%29%20%2A%201000%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28in%20papyro%29%20%2A%201000%29%3B%2Cc0)):

- [*in vitro*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_vitro) – in a glass,
- *[in vivo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_vivo)/[ex vivo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_vivo)* – in a living organism / not in a living organism,
- [*in situ*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ) – on site,
- [*in natura*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_natura) – in nature,
- [*in silico/silicio*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_silico) – in a computer (model),
- [*in simulacra/simulacris*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_simulacra) – in a model,
- [*in papyro*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_papyro) – on paper.

I am now looking for a concise analogous phrase to describe that a study was carried out **with a mathematical model**. I considered and was not happy with the following options so far:

- *In simulacris* – may as well apply to animal models, in vitro models, or other experimental models.
- *In mente* – implies that the entire study was carried out without the help of a computer or even paper.
- *In silicio* – excludes studies or parts of studies that were carried out in the mind or on paper.
- *In theoria* – is more narrow than *in simulacra,* but still contains qualitative scientific theories or models, respectively.
- *In mathematica* – Does not capture the modelling aspect very well; I might as well be engaging in pure mathematics. Moreover, it sounds as if I forgot to capitalise [Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica).
- *In simulacris mathematicis* – Fits, but lacks elegance.

Comment: Where would you like to use this phrase? If the context is scientific, I would put precision before elegance (and probably choose an English expression instead of a Latin one if you are writing in English). The preposition *in* is not such a good fit here, so I would use pure ablative, eg. *simulacro mathematico*, if I had to make the choice.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Precision is not everything in a scientific context. If I describe my studies in detail, I would not use a Latin phrase. But if I have to put studies in context, using a Latin phrase may underline the level or perspective I am talking about, in particular if I use the numerous existing parallels. The term *in silico* was established for a reason.

Comment: I was about to suggest "simulatio", but no, wait, that also means "deception" and "scam" -- probably not what you want.

Comment: *in silico* apparently took hold in English, but the correct L. would be *in silice*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is a bit oblique, I'll put up

> in harena

because it provides a natural way to work things out by hand, but involves the use of a tool, and so might easily extend to the use of computers more easily than would *in mente*.  If I recall correctly, it is conjectured that geometers would have worked out diagrams in tamped sand.

Comment: This is an amazingly good metaphor, really profound! I am wondering if *harena* is really idiomatic for the writing sand, which would more commonly be *pulvis*. Cf famous Cicero story of Archimedes (*pulvis et radius*), Persius *secto in pulvere metas*, Livy *in pulvere describere*. I do not recall any Classical use of *harena* in this sense, though.

Comment: There is a nice hidden feature here if you consider what sand is made of chemically.

Answer (score 2):

Given that [this](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulatio_computatralis) is the Vicipaedia article on computer models, I'd suggest:

> In simulatione

It doesn't quite fit -- like you pointed out -- but it's the best word I can find. It means "model", *seems* to have a connotation of "computer" or "mathematical", and is short enough.